# Adding files to Android System Folder

Tags: android, google-maps

Not all Android phones can support Google Maps. This is because of 2 missing files, namely: `com.google.android.maps.jar` & `com.google.android.maps.xml`. How do I add these files to the `etc` and `framework` folder of Android. **I want to do the file transfer programmatically.**

Is it possible to add files in the system memory? If not, can you give viable solution for Google Maps compatability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not have a native file browser, But there are numerous third-party ones `(Astro comes to mind)`.

`The filesystem of Android is that of Linux;`

The path separator is / and the FS grows from a single root called /. So, you have your app packages under `/data/apps`, and so forth.

Unless the phone is `jailbroken ("rooted")`, you won't get to see the whole filesystem - permissions get in the way.

This applies to all Android applications, they are `sandboxed` - that is, they don't get access the whole filesystem. There are API calls to get the path to the current application's sandbox directory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse DDMS File Explorer ther you will get one option called push a file on to device

before pushing you need to change read/write permission by below commands

```
adb shell
mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```